# Can anyone help me understand the directives and instructions from a small 16-bit DOS .COM program?

Tags: assembly, nasm, dos, x86-16

I'm learning assembly and I would like some help. If anyone can help me understand this pretty basic piece of code I would be grateful.

```
        org 100h; directive for compiler
        cpu 8086; cpu architecture 
        jmp START; this will jump the address of START from what i understood
BYTE1:  db 32; define byte 32 not sure what it does to be honest
TEXT1:  db 'Hardwarenahes Programmieren'; define a double byte
        times 4 db 0,'1';??? 
WORT1:  dw 1,2,3,4,1234 ;Define Word ???
        dd 1234h';??
START:  mov bx, BYTE1;move value if byte1 to bx register
WDH:    mov al, [bx]; pointer for bx register to move value into al register
        out 0, al;?
        inc bx;increment value of bx
        jmp WDH; jump to WDH and execute again
```

Answer (score 4):

> ```
>         org 100h; directive for compiler
> ```

The word “compiler” is inadequate:
Assembly programs are not “compiled”.
You say *compilation* if you are translating from a *more abstract* programming language to a more concrete “programming” language.
For instance Java → Java Bytecode.

Assembly language → machine code is not considered “compilation”, because both “languages” have the same “power”, are both as capable in describing an algorithm as the other.

[Documentation of the `org` directive](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.15.05/html/nasmdoc8.html#section-8.1.1).

> ```
>         cpu 8086; cpu architecture
> ```

The [`cpu` directive](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.15.05/html/nasmdoc7.html#section-7.11) *restricts* the set of available instructions.
In the following code the `nasm(1)` will, for instance, refuse to assemble the `cpuid` instruction.

> ```
>         jmp START; this will jump the address of START from what i understood
> ```

Yes.
It is used here, because in the flat `bin` format there are no sections.
That means, there is no indication “this is data” vs. “this is (instruction) code”.
From the processor’s point of view everything is code.
Jumping past the subsequent data is important, because otherwise the processor would interpret the following data values as instructions.

> ```
> BYTE1:  db 32; define byte 32 not sure what it does to be honest
> ```

There should have been a comment explaining this.
In ASCII, 32 is the decimal value of the space character (`' '`).

> ```
> TEXT1:  db 'Hardwarenahes Programmieren'; define a double byte
> ```

I believe the `d` in `db` stands for datum/data (I never saw a definite source claiming this).
The [`d…` pseudo-instructions](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.15.05/html/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.2.1) define (explicitly initialized) data.

> ```
>         times 4 db 0,'1';???
> ```

This is shorthand for `db 0, '1', 0, '1', 0, '1', 0, '1'`.
*Possibly* `0` means (if written to an appropriate device) “make a newline”, and (on IBM mainframes) writing `'1'` to the first column of a line means “advance to next page” (≈ form feed).

> ```
> WORT1:  dw 1,2,3,4,1234 ;Define Word ???
>         dd 1234h';??
> ```

The suffixes are (excerpt):

| suffix | stands for | size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `b` | byte | 8‑bit quantity |
| `w` | word | 16‑bit quantity |
| `d` | double word | 32‑bit quantity |
| `q` | quad-word | 64‑bit quantity |

The [trailing `h`](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.15.05/html/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.4.1) to the integer constant indicates a hexadecimal base.

> ```
> START:  mov bx, BYTE1;move value if byte1 to bx register
> ```

`BYTE1` is a label.
A label is a symbolic representation of an address.
This line loads *the address* that `BYTE1` represents into register `bx`.

> ```
> WDH:    mov al, [bx]; pointer for bx register to move value into al register
> ```

I think you understood this correctly, but your comment is a bit confusing, so I’ll rather write it out:

- `[bx]` means take the `bx` register and interpret it as a memory address.
- `al` is the lower half of the `ax` register. (`ah` would be the higher half.)
- `mov` paired with a memory operand as source, and an 8‑bit register as destination *copies* the contents found at the source into the destination.

> ```
>         out 0, al;?
> ```

On [x86](/questions/tagged/x86), hardware is accessed essentially in an `array`-like fashion. Here `0` is the index in this array and we write the contents of `al` to port `0`.
It would make sense if port `0` was connected to some kind of output device (printer/screen), but the meaning of the port `0` depends on the specific hardware configuration.

> ```
>         inc bx;increment value of bx
>         jmp WDH; jump to WDH and execute again
> ```

Yes.
From the German text I can suppose `WDH` stands for „wiederholen“ (repeat).

PS:
Maybe the book/tutorial you’re reading is too old?
(Advancing to the next [printed] page by writing `'1'` to the first column?)
There are some resources at the [x86 tag info page](/tags/x86/info).

Comment: I think the "d" in "db" stands for "define", but your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: COM1 is port 03f8.  Port 0 isn't usually anything, as far as I know. Once upon a time it was a DMA controller used with floppy disks.

Comment: @prl Thank you for your correction. I’ve actually never used a bare 8086.

Comment: "DB" most likely stands for "Define Byte", "Declare Byte", or "Data Byte".

Comment: @ecm Yeah, but do you have _a source_ corroborating this claim? Because “define Byte” or “data Byte” were _guesses_ of mine, too, you know.

Comment: @KaiBurghardt https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.mwftr.com/uC12/MASMReference.pdf&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwiAu_HW9uz6AhUwRfEDHcUGDsYQFnoECAkQAg&usg=AOvVaw0aUQC8CSGiH_NSkr3265vF This lists `DB` on page 27 (page 38 of the PDF) as "Can be used to define data like `BYTE`." So it'd seem to mean "define data byte".

Comment: @KaiBurghardt https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/convergent/manuals_b20/1166378_B20_MSDOS_Macro_Assembler_R2.0_Mar84.pdf&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwiAu_HW9uz6AhUwRfEDHcUGDsYQFnoECAsQAg&usg=AOvVaw3Sjjl7zhAB6I25d6NSPEbb On page 2-5 (PDF page 56) this lists: "<define-dir> is any of the five Define directives: DB, DW, DD, DQ, DT" and on page 4-7 (PDF page 106): "The DEFINE directives are used to define variables or to initialize portions of memory."

Comment: `dd 1234h';??` Do you happen to know whether that single quote would trigger a syntax error?

Comment: @SepRoland: Yes, the typewriter quote will trigger a syntax error. I ignored it presuming Ahmed’s been typing his comments on a US typewriter keyboard layout.

Comment: @ecm: Thank you for studying various assembler manuals. I’m now more _inclined_ to thinking it means “define …”. I still have my reservations. The problem is there is no _authoritative_ source. There is not _the_ assembly language, “ISO standard 1234”. The various assembler vendors have authority about _their own_ assembly language, yet still the `dx` pseudo-directives have different capabilities among various assemblers (e. g. something like `db ?` would be a `resb` in `nasm(1)`). I would’ve hoped to find some comment in `nasm`’s source code but couldn’t find any. :-/

Comment: @KaiBurghardt http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/intel/ISIS_II/121703-003_ASM86_Language_Reference_Manual_Mar85.pdf This probably originates from earlier than the Microsoft manuals. On page 3-4 (PDF page 36) it merely states "The DB, DW, DD, DQ, and DT directives are used to define variables and/or initialize memory." Doesn't seem like it explicitly calls them "define directives" like what I posted before.

Comment: @ecm That is definitely a weakness of assemblers in general, they're not standardized at all. I suppose it's fitting since the code isn't portable across hardware, but they didn't really need it to be not portable across different assemblers either